# Edit an embed message with an attachment for image doubles it in chat - Discord JDA

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I'm trying to edit the embed of a message with another embed. When i do so the image appears once more in chat on top of the edited embed. Is there a way to prevent this ?

```java
@Override
    public void onGuildReady(@NotNull GuildReadyEvent event) {
        super.onGuildReady(event);

        String fileName = "image.png";

        Guild guild = event.getGuild();
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/someResource.png");

        EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Title :")
        .setDescription("Description")
        .setImage("attachment://" + fileName)
        .setColor(new Color(255, 204, 81));
        guild.getTextChannels().get(0).sendMessage(eb.build()).addFile(in, fileName).queue(
                message -> {
                    MessageEmbed me = message.getEmbeds().get(0);
                    message.editMessage(
                            new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle(me.getTitle())
                            .setDescription(me.getDescription())
                            .setImage(me.getImage().getUrl())
                            .setColor(me.getColor())
                            .build()
                    ).queue();
                }
        );
    }
```

Result:

[image: Image doubled on top in chat]

Comment: Try to use TextChannel#sendMessage(File, filename).embed(eb.build()).queue()

Comment: I'm pretty sure the message is like that because you're sending the file twice, once in the `EmbedBuilder#setImage(String)` and once in `addFile(InputStream, String)`.

Comment: @Redi I guess you suggest me to use TextChannel#sendFile, if so, it produces exactly the same result as before.

Comment: @MrBorder, the thing is the image appears twice only after the message has been modified. Moreover i tried to call the MessageAction#clearFiles after editMessage(), it doesn't change a thing, the file is still displayed twice. Maybe the last method can't be used after a message edition. Anyway the problem remains strange, maybe it has to do with the way discord is linking embed image and files, in which case I wouldn't be able to do a thing to prevent it :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following line: `.setImage(me.getImage().getUrl())`, that line will return a discord url like `https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/203572340280262657/877103116036759642/unknown.png` and not `attachment://image.png`.

The image in the embed thus will be changed to the image from the url, and as discord isn't able to edit or delete attachments your initial image will get placed outside the embed.

One way to get around this is to use the following code:

```
guild.getTextChannels().get(0).sendFile(in, fileName).embed(eb.build()).queue(
            message -> {
                MessageEmbed me = message.getEmbeds().get(0);
                message.editMessage(
                        new EmbedBuilder(me)
                        .setTitle("New Title")
                        .build()
                ).queue();
            }
    );
```

`new EmbedBuilder(me)` will create an embedbuilder starting from another embed. If you use this you only need to set the parts of the embed which need to be changed and it will keep everything else.
Altough I prefer using `channel.sendFile(...).embed(..).queue()` as mentioned by Redi, your way of sending the image is equally correct.

If you want to change the image however then it's another story. As I mentioned before discord doesn't allow for attachments to be changed. There might be confusion around the [clearFiles](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/restaction/MessageAction.html#clearFiles()) method, but this method only closes files that are added to the [RestAction](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html) but not sent. The only way to be able to change the image after sending the embed is not using an attachment but using a normal url from the beginning. If you do this you can change the url later which will result in the image changing as it isn't an attachment.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete attached image =)

```
msg.edit({ embeds: [exampleEmbed], attachments: [] });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).